# ORA-01745: invalid host/bind variable name Issue

Tags: sql, oracle, hibernate

Getting the error for this query which looks valid.
JPA Hibernate native query execution

```sql
SELECT
  CASE_KEY,
  ENCRYPTED_CASE_ID,
  FILING_EPOCH_TIME AS CREATION_EPOCH_TIME,
  sql2u(SOURCE_LAST_UPDATE_DATETIME) as LAST_UPDATE_EPOCH_TIME
FROM CASE_DIM
WHERE CASE_KEY in (
  select * from (
    select distinct CASE_KEY
    from CASE_TRANSITION_FACT
    where CASE_EVENT_KEY BETWEEN :startKey AND :endKey order by CASE_KEY
  )
  where rownum between :fromRow and :toRow
)
```

Comment: If you try with different bind variable name then is it working? like use suffix `_1` in each bind variable name and check if it is working or not.

Comment: Debugging 101: Take out each bind variable, one by one, and run it after you take each one out. This will isolate which bind variable is causing the issue.

Comment: Your subquery is valid in the sense that it compiles but the logic seems odd. What exactly are you trying to achieve with that?

Comment: @Srini, what oracle version do you use?